# Possible number combinations within a range of sums

Tags: number-theory

I have a range of sums between $50$ and $100$

I need to determine how many possible combinations of $5$ unique selections between $1$ and $69$ will add up to a number this range.

So, for instance, let's say one possible combination would be:
$1+17+20+25+30 = 93$
or
$1+2+3+4+45 = 55$

How would I determine the $5$ unique selections to generate a sum within an acceptable range of between $50$ and $100$?

I know I've learned some of this before, but I can't find the right nomenclature for my searches so I can relearn it.

Comment: $15\not\in[50,100]$.

Comment: By unique selection, I assume you means the 5 numbers are distinct. By brute force, the number of combinations is $467711$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{rll}
\ds{\left. 1\right)} &
\mbox{Choose any}\ \ds{5}\ \mbox{numbers}\ \in\ \mathbb{N}_{\ 1\ \leq\ ?\ \leq\ 69}\
\mbox{such that their sum is}\ \ds{s}: &
\ds{\sum_{n_{1} = 1}^{69}\ldots\sum_{n_{5} = 1}^{69}
\bracks{\sum_{i = 1}^{5}n_{i} = s}}
\\ &\ds{\bracks{\cdots}}\ \mbox{is the}\ Iverson\ Bracket:\ \ds{\bracks{P} = 1}\
\mbox{whenever}\ \ds{P}\ \mbox{is}\ true
\\
&\mbox{and}\ \ds{0}\ otherwise.&
\\[5mm]
\ds{\left. 2\right)} & \mbox{Sum the above expression over all the values of}
\\
&\ds{s = 50,51,\ldots,99,100.}&
\end{array}\right.
$$

> Then, the answer is given by

\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\ds{\sum_{s = 50}^{100}\braces{%
\sum_{n_{1} = 1}^{69}\ldots\sum_{n_{5} = 1}^{69}
\bracks{\sum_{i = 1}^{5}n_{i} = s}}}} =
\sum_{s = 50}^{100}\braces{\sum_{n_{1} = 1}^{69}\ldots
\sum_{n_{5} = 1}^{69}\bracks{z^{s}}z^{\sum_{i = 1}^{5}n_{i}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\sum_{s = 50}^{100}\bracks{z^{s}}\pars{\sum_{n = 1}^{69}z^{n}}^{5} =
\sum_{s = 50}^{100}\bracks{z^{s}}\pars{z\,{z^{69} - 1 \over z - 1}}^{5} =
\sum_{s = 45}^{95}\bracks{z^{s}}{\pars{1 - z^{69}}^{5} \over \pars{1 - z}^{5}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\sum_{s = 45}^{95}\bracks{z^{s}}{1 - 5z^{69} \over \pars{1 - z}^{5}} =
\sum_{s = 45}^{95}\bracks{z^{s}}\pars{1 - z}^{-5} -
5\sum_{s = 45}^{95}\bracks{z^{s}}z^{69}\pars{1 - z}^{-5}
\\[5mm] = &\
\sum_{s = 45}^{95}\bracks{z^{s}}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{-5 \choose k}\pars{-z}^{k} -
5\sum_{s = 45}^{95}\bracks{z^{s}}z^{69}
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{-5 \choose k}\pars{-z}^{k}
\\[5mm] = &\
\sum_{s = 45}^{95}{-5 \choose s}\pars{-1}^{s} -
5\sum_{s = 45}^{95}\bracks{s \geq 69}{-5 \choose s - 69}\pars{-1}^{s - 69} =
\sum_{s = 45}^{95}{s + 4 \choose 4} -
5\sum_{s = 69}^{95}{s - 65 \choose 4}
\\[5mm] & =
\sum_{s = 0}^{50}{s + 49 \choose 4} - 5\sum_{s = 0}^{26}{s + 4 \choose 4}
\end{align}

> The binomial arguments are polynomials, in $\ds{s}$, of grade *four*.

Then,
$$
\bbx{\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\ds{\sum_{s = 50}^{100}\braces{%
\sum_{n_{1} = 1}^{69}\ldots\sum_{n_{5} = 1}^{69}
\bracks{\sum_{i = 1}^{5}n_{i} = s}}}} = 72\ 531\ 081}
$$

Answer (score 0):

By unique selection, I assume you mean the 5 numbers selected are distinct.
Furthermore, I will assume the order of selection doesn't matter. i.e. selections like $1+17+20+25+30 = 93$ and $30+17+20+25+1 = 93$ will be treated as same selection.

By brute force (i.e the most time consuming version of looping through everything), the number of combinations is $467711$.

Following is another way to derive the number mathematically (through we still need an CAS to complete some of the steps).

---

For any formal power series $\sum_{(i,j) \in \mathbb{N}^2} f_{ij} t^i x^j$
in $t$ and $x$. We will use the notation $[t^i x^j] (\cdots)$ to refer to the coefficient $f_{ij}$ in front of $t^i x^j$.

Let $A$ be any finite subset of positive integers. For any $m, n\in \mathbb{Z}_{+}$, the number of subsets of $A$ with $m$ elements whose element sum to $n$ is given by the formula

$$\mathcal{N} \stackrel{def}{=} \# \left\{ B \subset A : \# B = m \land \sum_{k\in B} k = n \right\}
= [t^m x^n ] \prod_{k\in A}( 1 + t x^k )$$

For the problem at hand, $m = 5$ and $A = \{ 1, \ldots, 69 \}$. We have

$$\mathcal{N} = \sum_{n=50}^{100} [t^5 x^n] \prod_{k=1}^{69} (1 + tx^k)
= [t^5 x^{100} ] \sum_{\ell=0}^{50} x^\ell \prod_{k=1}^{69} (1 + tx^k)
= [t^5 x^{100} ] \left(\frac{1-x^{51}}{1-x}\right)\prod_{k=1}^{69} (1 + tx^k)
$$
Expand the product into a polynomial in $t$.
$$\prod_{k=1}^{69}(1+tx^k) = 1 + \sum_{\ell=1}^{69} e_\ell(x) t^\ell
\quad\text{ where }\quad
e_\ell(x) = \sum_{1\le k_1 \le \ldots \le k_\ell \le 69} x^{k_1 + \cdots + k_\ell}$$ 
The coefficient $e_\ell(x)$ is the $\ell^{th}$ [elementary symmetric polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial) associated with the set $A' = \{ x^1, \ldots, x^{69} \}$. In terms of $e_\ell(x)$, we have

$$\mathcal{N} = [x^{100}]\left(\frac{1-x^{51}}{1-x}\right)e_5(x)$$

Let $p_\ell(x)$ be the [power sum symmetric polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_sum_symmetric_polynomial) associated with $A'$.

$$p_\ell(x) = \sum_{z \in A'} z^\ell = \sum_{k=1}^{69} x^{k\ell} = q_\ell(x)(1 - x^{69\ell}) \quad\text{ where }\quad q_\ell(x) = \frac{x^\ell}{1-x^\ell}$$
They are related to $e_\ell(x)$ through the 
[Newton–Girard formulae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_identities). In particular, we have

$$e_5(x) = \frac{1}{5!}
\left|\begin{matrix}
p_1(x) & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
p_2(x) & p_1(x) & 2 & 0 & 0\\
p_3(x) & p_2(x) & p_1(x) & 3 & 0\\
p_4(x) & p_3(x) & p_2(x) & p_1(x) & 4\\
p_5(x) & p_4(x) & p_3(x) & p_2(x) & p_1(x)
\end{matrix}\right|$$
Substitute $p_\ell(x) = q_\ell(x)(1-x^{69\ell})$ into this and throw away terms which don't contribute to $[x^{100}]$, we obtain ($q_\ell(x)$ abbreviated as $q_\ell$):

$$e_5(x) =
\frac{1}{5!}
\underbrace{\left|\begin{matrix}
q_1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
q_2 & q_1 & 2 & 0 & 0\\
q_3 & q_2 & q_1 & 3 & 0\\
q_4 & q_3 & q_2 & q_1 & 4\\
q_5 & q_4 & q_3 & q_2 & q_1
\end{matrix}\right|}_{ \Delta_5}
- \frac{x^{69}q_1}{4!}
\underbrace{\left|\begin{matrix}
q_1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
q_2 & q_1 & 2 & 0\\
q_3 & q_2 & q_1 & 3\\
q_4 & q_3 & q_2 & q_1\\
\end{matrix}\right|}_{\Delta_4}
+ o(x^{100})\\
{\Large\Downarrow}\\
\mathcal{N} 
= [x^{100}]\left( \frac{1-x^{51}}{5!(1-x)} \Delta_5 - \frac{x^{70}}{4!(1-x)^2}\Delta_4 \right)$$
With help on a CAS, this simplifies to
$$\mathcal{N} = [x^{100}] \frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}\quad\text{ where }\quad
\begin{cases}
P(x) &= x^{15}(1 - x^{51} - x^{65} - x^{66} - x^{67} - x^{68} - x^{69})\\
Q(x) &= (1-x)^2(1-x^2)(1-x^3)(1-x^4)(1-x^5)\\
&=  1- 2x + x^3 + x^5 - 2x^8 + x^{11} + x^{13} - 2x^{15} + x^{16}
\end{cases}
$$
Expand $\frac{1}{Q(x)}$ as a power series in $x$, $\displaystyle\;\frac{1}{Q(x)} = s_0 + s_1 x + s_2 x^2 + \cdots$. The coefficients $s_k$ can be computed using following recurrence relation:
$$
\begin{cases}
n < 0, & s_n = 0,\\
n = 0, & s_n = 1,\\
n > 0, & s_n - 2s_{n-1} + s_{n-3} + s_{n-5} - 2s_{n-8} + s_{n-11} + s_{n-13} - 2s_{n-15} + s_{n-16} = 0
\end{cases}
$$
The end result is
$$\begin{align}\frac{1}{Q(x)} 
 = &\;\; 1+2x+4x^2 +7x^3 + \cdots \\
   & + 509x^{16}+628x^{17}+769x^{18}+933x^{19}+1125x^{20} + \cdots\\
   & + 8837x^{34} + \cdots\\
   & + 480512x^{85} + \cdots
\end{align}$$

In terms of $s_k$, we find
$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{N} &= [x^{100}]  \frac{x^{15}(1 - x^{51} - x^{65} - x^{66} - x^{67} - x^{68} - x^{69})}{Q(x)}\\
&= \left([x^{85}] - [x^{34}] - [x^{20}] - [x^{19}] - [x^{18}] - [x^{17}] - [x^{16}]\right)\frac{1}{Q(x)}\\
&= s_{85} - s_{34} - s_{20} - s_{19} - s_{18} - s_{17} - s_{16}\\
&= 480512 - 8837 - 1125 - 933 - 769 - 628 - 509\\
&= 467711
\end{align}
$$

Reproducing what we have obtained by brute force.